# Announce or Open tab/window if minimized on Event jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if in jQuery API is there a function/option to get an active tab of browser or window on event/success if it is minimized or another window/tab is active.

The idea is that I have a long polling with jQuery and on get success it will need to announce the user that there is an event but I cannot find the right function/option on jQuery or Javascript.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: I am confused, do you want to maximize the window when you are done with a long running task?

Comment: No, what i want is to wake up that window on event, so if the user is in My Computer for example or is in another tab or another Browser, on event it need to bring up the window. Thanks